# Running multiple specs using Protractor results in a percentage of them timing out

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Running multiple test specs using Protractor results in some of them timing out, giving the following error:

```
Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
```

The failure is not consistent; not the same specs fail with each run but a percentage of the specs do and they vary from time to time. below is the config file for Protractor:

```js
'use strict';

exports.config = {
  baseUrl: 'http://www.example.com/',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu"]
    },
    specs: 'specs/**/*Spec.js'

    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 4
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "protractor conf.js",
    "test-in-parallel": "node -r parallel-protractor node_modules/.bin/protractor conf.js"
  },
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
  getPageTimeout: 30000,
  restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
  }
};
```

**Note: I have tried increasing the timeout interval for Jasmine but a percentage of the specs fail anyway (they just take a longer time to do so)**

Comment: While trouble shooting remove anything that adds complexity.  Like try doing it without the chrome options.  Do the tests do anything?  If they do try more generic tests and check for anything where the tests are use the same resource.

Comment: Chuck Brown ..Excellent point.Always simplify the problem in its most basic form.

Comment: Please try running them without headless mode and in sequential manner then post the results.One by one.